# Illegal character in path (of Resources file)

Tags: vb.net, com, resources

I have a Windows Control Library project (visual studio 2010). I put in the compile tab for it to be a com element (I use it as an addin for another program).

My question is the following:
I have a .cvs file in my resources that I use to parse some main settings.
The line of code that reads this file gives an error when I run the addin.
 code line:

```
dim reader as new streamReader(My.Resources.standards)
```

(the file is called standards)

error I get when running the com element:

```
Illegal character in path.
```

The program runs nicely when I test it as a normal windows form project.

Anyone know how to fix this? Or how to do decent debugging when testing com elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not have anything to do with COM, scratch that as a cause of your problem.  Clearly your `My.Resources.standards` property returns a *string*, not a stream.  Which is pretty normal when you add a text file as a resource.  It makes StreamReader try to open a file on disk using the content of the .cvs resource as the path of the file.  That will of course not work well.

You could use a StringReader instead.  Or just use the returned string as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to following
dim reader = new string(My.Resources.standards)
you have a string now that can be used in regex
Cobus