# illegal characters in path using System.Speech.Recognition

Tags: vb.net

I  have an error with some code that I have been working on for a while. I am writing a speech recognition software in Visual Basic.

`grammar.Append(New Choices(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(My.Resources.Commands)))`

The above line has illegal characters in path in the InnerException. however if the line of code bellow is in place instead of the one above it will run fine.

`C:\Users\oem\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\VC\VC\CustomCommmands.txt`

This will now work if the application is compiled into a exe setup and ran on a different machine.

I have looked all over Google for a answer, but  none seem to work.  If anyone can shed some light, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of `My.Resources.Commands`?

Comment: What do u mean by value. inside the text file there are commands that the software will recognize these are each on there on line for example Hello is on its own line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Illegal character in path (of Resources file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702874/illegal-character-in-path-of-resources-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` is only used when you are reading a file from disk.  It sounds like you have embedded the file as a resource in your program.

I don't have vb.net to test this, but this will probably work...  I believe `My.Resources` loads the resource values directly, so you don't have to load them at all.

`grammar.Append(New Choices(My.Resources.Commands))`